# How to user prefix 'N' for unicode with nvarchar variable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to user prefix 'N' for unicode with nvarchar variable in SQL Server?  For example:

Given this variable:

```
declare @Query1 nvarchar(max)
```

I can assign to it like this:

```
set @Query1 = N'لاحظات'
```

But what if I want to use `N@Query1` somewhere?

Comment: declare @Query nvarchar(max)
declare @Query1 nvarchar(max)
  set @Query1 = 'لاحظات'
we can use N'لاحظات', but what to do if I want to use N@Query1?
@Query1 dynamically comes from DB.

Comment: if @Query1 **IS** a NVARCHAR variable, then it **IS** a NVARCHAR variable and you don't need to prefix it with another 'N' to make it NVARCHAR.... just use it

Answer (score 11):

You only need to use N'xyz' when you have literal text.  Once the nvarchar data is in a variable or result set column of nvarchar data type you no longer need to use the N'...' notation, the system knows the data type at that point.

try it out:

```
DECLARE @A   nvarchar(100)
       ,@B   nvarchar(100)
SET @A = N'anything here!!'

SET @B=@A --would work the same if coming from a query result set as well

SELECT @B --will show special unicode characters
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @nv1 nvarchar(50) = N'لاحظات', @nv2 nvarchar(50) = 'لاحظات', @v varchar(50) = N'لاحظات'     
declare @nv3 nvarchar(50) = @nv1 + ' hallo', @nv4 nvarchar(50) = @nv1 + N' hallo'

select @nv1, @nv2, @nv3, @nv4, @v
```

Answer (score 0):

It is used with string literals to indicate the text should be treated as unicode.  e.g.

```
DECLARE @something NVARCHAR(100)
SET @something = N'sometext'
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to use with @something not with string. how can I?

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @var nvarchar(255)

Set @var = N'Hello World'
print @var

create table #tmp( columnA nvarchar(255) not null)
insert into #tmp(columnA) Values (N'Test')

Select @var = columnA from #tmp
print @var
drop table #tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to marc_s for his answer, that solved my problem.
I highlight it here as an answer for those who can't find it.

"
if @Query1 IS a NVARCHAR variable, then it IS a NVARCHAR variable and you don't need to prefix it with another 'N' to make it NVARCHAR.... just use it 
"