# Create a list of album titles and the unit prices for the artist "Audioslave" from given ER diagram in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given the ER diagram can someone please provide me with the code for SQLite to find the query as asked in the question.[image]

I'm using Chinook Database

EDITED - Below is the code I'm attaching which I used to get the query, but unfortunately, the answer which I'm getting is wrong

```
SELECT a.Title, t.UnitPrice
FROM Albums a, Tracks t
WHERE t.AlbumId IN
      (SELECT a.AlbumId
       FROM Albums a
       WHERE a.ArtistID IN
             (SELECT ar.ArtistID
              FROM Artists ar
              WHERE ar.Name = 'Audioslave'))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give us your text instead of image to help other people to be able to reproduce.

Comment: @Anonymous, I've edited the question, please see it again and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you need:

```
SELECT a.Title, t.UnitPrice
FROM Albums a 
INNER JOIN Tracks t ON a.AlbumId = t.AlbumId
INNER JOIN Artists ar ON ar.ArtistID = a.ArtistID 
WHERE ar.Name = 'Audioslave'
```

If you want to do this using the query you wrote, you need to add a condition in the `where` clause of the outer query to join `album` and `track` tables (`AND a.AlbumId = t.AlbumId`):

```
SELECT a.Title, t.UnitPrice
FROM Albums a, Tracks t
WHERE t.AlbumId IN
      (SELECT a.AlbumId
       FROM Albums a
       WHERE a.ArtistID IN
             (SELECT ar.ArtistID
              FROM Artists ar
              WHERE ar.Name = 'Audioslave'))
AND a.AlbumId = t.AlbumId
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in this simple way

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Title, t.UnitPrice
FROM Albums a 
INNER JOIN Tracks t ON a.AlbumId = t.AlbumId
INNER JOIN Artists ar ON ar.ArtistID = a.ArtistID 

WHERE ar.Name = 'Audioslave'
```

**Updated**

The relationship between `albums` and `artist` is 1-to-many, you might use `DISTINCT` to avoid duplication value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Quamer Nasim

Comment: bro as you can see in the ER diagram that there is no ArtistID in tracks table then how come t.ArtistID? and what's with the prefix N in N'Audioslave'. And what if i want to do it with the help of subqueries to understand the concept of subqueries in a better wau, can you help me out with the code for subqueries

Comment: I've just updated my answer. `a.ArtistID` instead of `t.ArtistID` Please take a look @Quamer Nasim Let me know if you need any help

Comment: and what about the prefix N in the line WHERE ar.Name = N'Audioslave'?

Comment: As you can see  in ER `name` with type is `NVARCHAR(120)` So your data can also store [`unicode` value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836606/how-to-user-prefix-n-for-unicode-with-nvarchar-variable-in-sql-server). So you should add `N` prefix to cover all cases

Comment: I've just updated my answer with more details. Please take a look @Quamer Nasim

Comment: Bro, I ran your code but it's giving an error which says ```near "'Audioslave'": syntax error``` and when I'm removing that prefix N, it's working fine. I'm using SQLite, are you sure that this prefix thing works in SQLite. And I'll for sure accept your answer but it has to work for me without any errors, right. Although I thank you for taking the time to answer my query

Comment: Sorry, you are using `SQLite`, Okie. I updated my answer, please take a look @Quamer Nasim. Have a nice day bro.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use AND command in JOIN to reduce the number of records fetched. This improves the processing time and use less memory

```
SELECT artists.Name
,artists.Artistid
,albums.Albumid
,albums.Title
,tracks.Unitprice
,tracks.name
FROM
  artists INNER JOIN albums
    ON artists.Artistid = albums.Artistid
    and artists.Name  = 'Audioslave'
  INNER JOIN tracks 
    ON albums.albumid = tracks.albumid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select al.title, tr.unitprice 
from albums as al 
inner join tracks as tr  
on tr.albumid= al.albumid 
where  al.artistid = (select artistid from artists where name = 'Audioslave')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
artists.Name
,tracks.UnitPrice
FROM ((albums INNER JOIN tracks ON albums.AlbumId = tracks.AlbumId)
INNER JOIN artists ON artists.Artistid = albums.Artistid)
WHERE artists.Name = 'Audioslave'
```

Without going for a subquery we can easily do this by using  "INNER JOIN"

1. SELECT the columns you want to display as output (Since we are using INNER JOIN we can put all the columns we are trying to retrieve from all the tables that we intend to JOIN.
2. From the "FROM" statement we start to JOIN the tables based on a primary key. We initially link two tables and thereafter link any other tables we want, one by one specifying the primary key in which we intend to link it together.
3. Finally we use a filter to filter out the required information, where in this case is using the "WHERE" clause and specifying to filter for artist name as "Audioslave".

Hope this would help and please comment if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.UnitPrice,b.Title,b.Name
From (select tracks.AlbumId,invoice_items.UnitPrice
From tracks
Left join invoice_items
ON tracks.TrackId=invoice_items.TrackId) as a
Left join (select artists.Name,albums.Title,albums.AlbumId
From artists
Left join albums
on artists.ArtistId=albums.ArtistId) as b
on a.AlbumId=b.AlbumId
where b.Name="Audioslave";
```

Answer (score -2):

> SELECT t.UnitPrice , a.Title

> FROM   tracks t , albums a

> WHERE ( t.AlbumId= a.AlbumId and ArtistId=
>
> > ```
> >                          (select ArtistId
> > ```

> > ```
> >                           from artists
> > ```

> > ```
> >                            where Name="Audioslave"))
> > ```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2):

> select t.UnitPrice ,a.Title

> from tracks t ,albums a , artists ar

> where (t.AlbumId= a.AlbumId and a.ArtistId=ar.ArtistId and ar.Name="Audioslave")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).